# PushSharp sending notifications to iOS successful but not received

Tags: c#, ios, pushsharp

I'm using the latest PushSharp (4.0.10) to send notifications to iOS and Android devices. About 9 months ago I tested this out and it seemed to work fine. I tried the same application today and the device (iPhone) no longer receives the notifications. The device token was updated today so it should be valid.
The apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded event gets fired but the device never gets the notification. 
There's no exceptions or any other type of feedback.

```
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, "mycert.p12", "password");

        // Create a new broker
        var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

        // Wire up events
        apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) =>
        {

            aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
            {

                // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
                if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
                {
                    var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

                    // Deal with the failed notification
                    var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                    var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Apple Notification Failed: ID={apnsNotification.Identifier}, Code={statusCode}");

                }
                else
                {
                    // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException           
                    Console.WriteLine($"Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}");
                }

                // Mark it as handled
                return true;
            });
        };

        apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Apple Notification Sent!");
        };

        // Start the broker
        apnsBroker.Start();

        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var aps = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        aps.Add("alert", GetAlert());
        aps.Add("badge", 1);
        aps.Add("sound", "chime.aiff");
        payload.Add("aps", aps);            
        payload.Add("data", "info");


        apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
        {
            DeviceToken = textBox1.Text,
            Payload = JObject.Parse( Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload))
        });

        apnsBroker.Stop();
```

Comment: are you updating the token to your sever when ever you got a new token from APNs? Else, are you caching the token once you got it?

Comment: I always update the token to make sure it's not expired.

Comment: Can you past the code of token receive?

Comment: It looks like the issue is being caused by someone messing with the app and causing it to lose it's notification permissions.

Comment: @jbassking10  did you find any solution. I am experiencing exactly same issue.

Comment: @Mr.Jay Make sure you have assigned Push Notifications capability in Xcode before building the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is working example. Install Pushsharp and execute this code.
Make sure you should have valid device token + certificate + certificate password.

```
private void SendIOSPushNotification()
{
    try
    {
         //Get Certificate
         var appleCert = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Certificates_new.p12"));

         // Configuration (NOTE: .pfx can also be used here)
         var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServer## Heading ##Environment.Sandbox, appleCert, "YourCertificatePassword");

         // Create a new broker
         var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

         // Wire up events
         apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) =>
         {
             aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
             {
                 // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
                 if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
                 {
                     var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

                     // Deal with the failed notification
                     var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                     var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

                     Console.WriteLine($"Apple Notification Failed: ID={apnsNotification.Identifier}, Code={statusCode}");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException          
                     Console.WriteLine($"Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}");
                 }
                 // Mark it as handled
                 return true;
             });
         };

         apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Apple Notification Sent!");
         };

         var fbs = new FeedbackService(config);
         fbs.FeedbackReceived += (string deviceToken, DateTime timestamp) =>
         {
             lblResult.Text = deviceToken +" Expired";
             // Remove the deviceToken from your database
             // timestamp is the time the token was reported as expired
         };

         // Start Proccess 
         apnsBroker.Start();

         //Device Token
         //string _deviceToken = "8b5f6b908ae3d84a3a9778b1f5f40cc73b33fe2  ?    5431e41702cee6e90c599f1e3";
         string[] deviceTokens = "8b5f6b908ae3d84a3a9778b1f5f40cc73b33fe25431e41702cee6e90c599f1e3,0592798256a0d2f9e00ea366d5bd3595789fa0f551431f1d707cab76d933c25c".Split(',');

         foreach (string _deviceToken in deviceTokens)
         {
             apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
             {
                 DeviceToken = _deviceToken,
                 Payload = JObject.Parse(("{\"aps\":{\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"oven.caf\",\"category\":\"NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY\",\"alert\":\"" + (txtMessage.Text.Trim() + "\"}}")))
             });
         }

         apnsBroker.Stop();
         //lblResult.Text = "Messages sent";
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }
}
```